# How to get the page and paragraph number for all comments and tracked changes?

Tags: microsoft-word, script, microsoft-word-2010

I have marked up a document with comments and tracked changes in Word 2010.  However, I've been asked to restructure those comments and tracked changes to a single document with page numbers AND paragraph numbers and (if possible) sentence numbers. Is there a way (or script) to do this?

Comment: Though programming you have access to almost all of a Word document. Just depends on how involved you want it to be. If you are doing this repeatedly it would be worthwhile to script. Sounds like in this case it might be quicker to do manually than trying to write something.

Comment: I suspect I'll be doing it repeatedly.  I'll look into scripting options.  It just seemed like a common enough occurrence that somebody might have already written a script.